# Discord server leaking IP addresses

Tags: account-security

I was on Discord, and someone sent me an invite to a server called "Operation: Pridefall".

I didn't know what it was, the link is `http://discord.gg/xxxxxxxxx` - and the invite was legit.

I thought it was just a regular chat. I looked, and there was some IP addresses being leaked.

I asked the person who invited me, "What is this?". They said "Look it up, it's exposing LGBT people"... I do not hate gays at all, and so they might dox me.

I have changed my discord password. But I don't know what else to do, and if this is legitimate. I do not know if it's possible to hack someone through a Discord 
invite.

Please let me know what to do.

Comment: If someone knew my public IP, they can roughly tell which part of the country I'm from. My IP right now is `212.95.8.233`. I'm telling you that because IP alone means nothing.

Comment: Thanks. Well, after my anxiety was over, I logged out of Discord from my first phone, and used my second phone to login and change my password and delete my account altogether. Do you think that merely logging in to a targetted Discord from my second phone could expose its contents to potential threat?

Comment: "Is it possible..." are bad ways to frame a question in information security. I don't know how the Discord app works internally. There might be a vulnerability that allows this, there might not be. The only answer I can comfortably give is "I don't know for sure". However, I think you worry entirely too much about this.

Comment: Thank you sir. I apologize for my framing of the question. I'm stressed. - Shall I factory reset the phone or just get a new one?

Comment: I think you should just calm down and keep cool.

Comment: Do you know what "doxxing" means? It means publicizing private persally identidfiable information, such as your name, your address or your social security number. An IP address is none of these things.

Comment: Yes, but is it not strange that they can grab your IP merely by having you click on their profile picture? I thought that Discord is entirely server-based, and that the client communicates with the discord server which in turn resends data to other clients.

Comment: How do you know for sure that this is how it works? How do you know that it's not a bot that automatically publishes the IP of anyone connecting? You make so many assumptions and yet have so little actual evidence.

Comment: I am sorry for my assumptions sir. Well if it is a bot, does this mean that Marty's answer is wrong? (First paragraph)? He describes Discord as entirely server-based. Further, please tell me how to change my IP.

Comment: Please stop posting a link that you, yourself, are sure is dangerous.

Comment: @schroeder I apologize, my bad. I just wanted someone who is more experienced to see for himself what is going on (and if I'm misinterpreting things), but you are correct. Here are the measures that I will take so far: 1- Throw away my devices. 2- Contact my ISP and ask them to change my IP 3- Access my emails and change all passwords. What else would you advise that I do?

Comment: I would do none of those things

Comment: What do you advise that I do in order to prevent them from accessing my devices and network?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a default password on your internet router... That's it

Comment: My router password is complex. But how is that useful for a hacker? Could they access my router itself through my IP?

Comment: I have just changed my router password to a more complex password.

Comment: I have seen they were posting things like MAC address, IPs, device info, etc. are these useful for gaining remote access to someone's device/

Comment: @schroeder could you please tell me in a nutshell: is it possible to grab someone's IP simply from a Discord invite/call, and how that could be used to know your MAC address, device info. etc, and how these details could be used to access your phone?

Comment: Knowing your MAC address is useless. Knowing the model of your router is equally useless. And knowing your public IP (which you can change by asking your ISP) will not allow them access to your phone.

Answer (score 5):

Discord itself is entirely server-based, as described in this [Discord blog post](https://blog.discord.com/how-discord-handles-two-and-half-million-concurrent-voice-users-using-webrtc-ce01c3187429#guiding-principles). In other words, your client is always directly communicating with a Discord server, which then re-sends your data to other clients. That means any potential attacker will see the Discord server's IP and not yours.

However, that doesn't have to be the case for other online services, which you can link in your profile. When you join a server, other users, as well as bots and user-bots, in that server will gain access to the data in your Discord profile, which they can scrape and **potentially** use to track down your IP. You can see which services you have linked to your account by going to the **User Settings** and choosing the **Connections** category.

**Your best course of action right now is staying calm.** They might try to use the pressure to their advantage and try to direct you to a phishing site to get your Discord credentials or scan a [login QR code](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039213771-QR-Code-Login-FAQ). By just following an official Discord invite (the `https://discord.gg/xxxxxx` format), your credentials are safe.

Furthermore, the things you described do violate the [Discord's Terms of Service](https://discord.com/terms) in multitude of ways. You can report the server to Discord's Trust and Safety, as described in [this support article](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000291932).

After you're done with the report (since it requires you to get the server ID, which requires you to be present in the server), or immediately, if you're not planning on making a report, I recommend you to **leave the server** and **report + block anyone** trying to threaten/blackmail you afterwards. You're most likely not dealing with a nation-state or an organized crime group, just a group of kids having no better way to entertain themselves during the quarantine, and are safe to ignore their threats. After all, credible online threats can still be subject to prosecution and should things escalate even more, you can report them directly to the authorities.

Lastly, as a general advice, I'd highly recommend [enabling two-factor authentication](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/219576828-Setting-up-Two-Factor-Authentication) on Discord if you haven't done that already.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108788/discussion-on-answer-by-marty-cagas-discord-server-doxing-people).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think much bad can come out of you just joining the server and leaving it shortly after. AFAIK, most people have dynamic IP addresses, meaning your IP address will change about every time you connect to the Internet. This means that somebody recording the IP address from which you connected isn't that much of a threat. I think that Discord should be relatively secure, so I don't think you can harm someone via an invitation. Even changing the password seems like an overkill, although it's good that you take your security seriously and it obviously never harms to change your password.
Googling "operation pridefall" has returned some info on it, you might want to check it out for context. To me it seems like people behind it are just extremist trolls wanting to spread mean comments around the time of pride month, not someone very dangerous.

To sum up, I don't think you have something to worry about and I wouldn't worry too much about personal security. Observing good security practices, like using up-to-date operating system and software, choosing more secure software alternatives to less secure ones, using strong passwords and two-factor authentication, at least where it matters, is always good. Aside from that, doxing might potentially be a crime, depending on details and jurisdiction, so perhaps reporting it might be appropriate, either to Discord or to local law enforcement (or both).

All of the above is just my opinion and contains some subjectivity. It can also be at parts inaccurate. Normally I would not post such an answer, but you seem distressed, so I thought that my outlook will be better than nothing.

Comment: Further, I joined the server twice. Didn't click any links. But, my worry is that links aren't needed for some hackers (they seemed professional).

Comment: Well, it's somewhat possible for them to get your IP I think, but even that is not very concerning, as just the knowledge of someone's IP is not very much.
About the phone, it's very unlikely that an attacker would gain any access.
About the hackers, I'm pretty sure they can only talk big. All the talk about "grabbing IPs" and trying to appear threatening is kind of signature of "script kiddies". I've got some of that too on a couple occasions and nothing remotely bad ever happened. I would believe it's bluff and power play.

Comment: By no means let yourself be "social engineered" into doing something that attackers could actually use. It's best not to talk at all with them. Threatening the victim into giving some information, going to a website (which could try to infect you're machine with malware for example) or anything like that could actually enable them to do some damage in some circumstances.

Comment: Accessing someone's phone like that is really top notch hacking that I really, really don't think could happen here. I know various national security agencies can manage it. About your IP you can check it by just searching "what's my ip" in Google or DuckDuckGo. You can note it down, then disconnect from the internet and check back after a while. It's most likely to be different then.

Comment: I've heard in the US people sometimes get static IPs just like that, but it appears to be uncommon nowadays. Here where I live it never happens, you have to get a special contract with your ISP to have a static IP.

Comment: Thank you. I certainly did not click on any links, aside from the official Discord invite itself.  Should I just throw away my phone, or is a factory reset enough?

Comment: Factory reset is already too much in my view. I wouldn't recommend doing even that. Of course if you want to do that and it will make you feel safer it won't hurt, but I don't see a reason to go to such extremes. Just logging to a Discord server from a phone is not enough leverage for them to gain access to your device.
To be continued

Comment: The main technique of such "hackers" is scaring someone into doing something they would benefit from, either by gaining further leverage (for example they ask someone to email them to get real name, from there they can checkout Facebook etc.) or by direct extortion of goods. They might also enjoy scaring people and getting the feel of power over them. The truth is, it's unlikely there's any real power involved. 20 years ago it was different, as many services and devices were poorly secured, but nowadays you should be just fine if you observe good practices and don't talk to those goons.

Comment: Thank you. Someone said that it is possible to get info from DMs. I only did reply to one of their DMs. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how much info one can get from a DM on Discord. I really doubt it's much useful info, though. From an email one can get someone's IP (not always, modern email servers can delete this info), the email client and its version and operating system and its version. Those data are rather harmless. I doubt Discord gives even that and I would be really surprised if it gave more than that.

Comment: Thanks. Well on the server, you could see that they were posting people's MAC address, IPs, device info, and such. Are these useful for entering into someone's device/connection?

Comment: I'm concerned about this. I have messaged Discord, but their reply was basically "nobody can see your IP through discord"... could there be a glitch or issue within the discord app?

Comment: The info could have come from some other source too. Email, for example, can leak a lot of data, so can websites, public Wi-Fi networks etc. Those data can be helpful for an attacker, knowing something is never worse than not knowing it, but again, it's not very concerning, MACs, IPs and device info are essentially public data. Every server you connect to knows your IP and every website knows your device and OS info. Similarly you can get the same info about the servers you connect to. Bottom line: it's pretty harmless info in general